# Blank row after header

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing existing excel by merging many excel files, after generating of final excel file blank row is adding up after headers.

Below is my code which reads data from multiple files and write to particular blank file which have pivot formulas set.

I tried even by 
1. Setting `createRow(0)` , then started filling data from next row.
2. Tried of maintaining `int` counter, but still didn't work
3. Tried incrementing `getLastRowNum()` count, but no use

```
public class DCSReadImpl implements ReadBehavior {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DCSReadImpl.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public Sheet readReport(Workbook workbook,Map<String,String> masterMap, Properties properties) {
        //int firstRow = 0;
        int outRowCounter = 0;
        String fileToMove= "";
        boolean headers = true;
        Row outputRow = null;
        Sheet outputSheet = null;
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        try {

            outputSheet = wb.createSheet("Data");


            log.info("**** Set headers start"); // this used to be different method
            int cellNo = 0;
            outputRow = outputSheet.createRow(0);

            for(String headerName : ReportConstants.DCS_OUTPUT_HEADER){
                outputRow.createCell(cellNo).setCellValue(headerName);
                cellNo++;
            }

            //outRowCounter++;
            log.info("**** Set headers completed");

            log.info("Read input file(s) for DCS report");
            log.info("Input File Path : " + properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_PATH));

            File inputDir = new File(properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_PATH));
            File[] dirListing = inputDir.listFiles();

            if (0 == dirListing.length) {
                throw new Exception(properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_PATH) + " is empty");
            }
            for (File file : dirListing) {
                log.info("Processing : " + file.getName());
                fileToMove = file.getName();
                XSSFWorkbook inputWorkbook = null;
                try {
                    inputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new Exception("File is already open, please close the file");
                }

                XSSFSheet inputsheet = inputWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
                Iterator<Row> rowItr = inputsheet.iterator();
                int headItr = 0;
                //log.info("Validating headers : " + file.getName());
                while (rowItr.hasNext()) {
                    Row irow = rowItr.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellItr = irow.cellIterator();
                    int cellIntItr = 0;
                    String key = "";

                    int rowN = outputSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
                    outputRow = outputSheet.createRow(rowN);

                    Cell outCell = null;
                    while (cellItr.hasNext()) {
                        Cell inputCell = cellItr.next();

                        if (0 == inputCell.getRowIndex()) {
                            if (!FileUtility.checkHeaders(headItr, inputCell.getStringCellValue().trim(),
                                    ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_HEADER)) {
                                throw new Exception("Incorrect header(s) present in Input File, Expected : "
                                        + ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_HEADER[headItr]);
                            }
                            headItr++;
                        } else {
                            //outCell = outputRow.createCell(cellIntItr);
                            if (0 == inputCell.getColumnIndex()) {
                                key = inputCell.getStringCellValue().trim();
                            } else if (2 == inputCell.getColumnIndex()) {
                                key = key + ReportConstants.DEL + inputCell.getStringCellValue().trim();
                            }


                            if (7 == cellIntItr){

                                outCell = outputRow.createCell(cellIntItr);
                                outCell.setCellValue(getValue(masterMap, key, 0));
                                cellIntItr++;

                                outCell = outputRow.createCell(cellIntItr);
                                outCell.setCellValue(getValue(masterMap, key, 1));
                                cellIntItr++;

                                outCell = outputRow.createCell(cellIntItr);
                                outCell.setCellValue(getValue(masterMap, key, 2));
                                cellIntItr++;
                            }

                            // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                            switch (inputCell.getCellType()) {

                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                outCell = outputRow.createCell(cellIntItr);
                                outCell.setCellValue(inputCell.getNumericCellValue());
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                outCell = outputRow.createCell(cellIntItr);
                                outCell.setCellValue(inputCell.getStringCellValue().trim());
                                break;
                            }
                            cellIntItr++;
                        }
                    }
                    //outRowCounter ++ ;
                }
                if(!fileToMove.isEmpty()){
                    FileUtility.checkDestinationDir(""+properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_ARCHIVE_PATH));
                    FileUtility.moveFile(properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_PATH) + fileToMove,
                            properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_ARCHIVE_PATH)+fileToMove+FileUtility.getPattern());
                    }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occured : ", e);
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\DCS\\Output\\Krsna_"+FileUtility.getPattern()+".xlsx");
            wb.write(outputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputSheet;
    }

    private String getValue(Map<String, String> masterMap, String cellKey, int index) {

        String value = masterMap.get(cellKey);
        if (null != value) {
            String cellValue[] = value.split("\\" + ReportConstants.DEL);
            return cellValue[index];
        } else {
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

There should not be blank row after header row. That is in between of 0th row and 1st row (hope my understanding is correct on row indexing). I know this is very basic question :-(

Comment: The problem is that you always create a new row in `outputSheet` even if the row in `inputsheet` is the header row having row index 0. Then your code does not write something in that row. But the row is created. Try `... int rowN = outputSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; if (irow.getRowNum() > 0) outputRow = outputSheet.createRow(rowN); else outputRow  = null; ...`. Then in further code check if `outputRow ` is `null` before using it.

Comment: @AxelRichter this worked like a charm. Please post this as a answer